# html textlabel height and width is not changing

Tags: html, css

In my HTML i can't change height and width of the label through css.
But I can change top and left.

HTML:

```
<div id="loginname"> 
    <label for="lognametext"></label> 
    <input type="text"  class="required" name="loginnametext"
           id="loginnametext" maxlength="500" /></div>
```

CSS:

```
#loginname { 
    left: 460px; 
    top: 18px; 
    position: absolute;
    margin-bottom: 0; 
    height: 28px; 
    width: 10px; 
    background-color: #fff;     
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the width and height of the text input, you can't do that by changing the width and height of the container (the div tag). You need to either set the style attribute of the text input, or set the css of the id "loginnametext" as you did with the div tag.

Alternatively, you could keep the width and height set for the div tag, and set the width and height of the text input to "100%" without quotes.

Comment: as written in my question i want to change the width of label. i.e. container

Comment: Ah, if you want to change the width and height of the label, you need to set the css for #lognametext, which is the id of the label tag.